# reparenting hierarchyid values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

If I have the following rows set up in a SQL Server 2008 table:

```
Row        Hierarchy
1          1/
2          2/
3          1/1
4          1/2
5          2/1
6          2/2
7          2/1/1
```

Currently row 5 is parented to row 2.  I want to reparent row 5 to row 1, so it would now become 1/3 instead of 2/1.  That much I have working so far.  I want row 7 (and any other rows down the chain) to remain parented to row 5, which means row 7 should be 1/3/1.  What would be some efficient sql to ensure that the hierarchy ids of all children records down the chain get updated as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The silence is deafening!

Have you read this? [Reordering Data in a Hierarchical Table Using Hierarchical Methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677256.aspx)

Comment: Booya!  I think that's exactly what I wanted to know.  Thanks.